# Макросом увеличить/уменьшить значение ячейки на единицу

Tags: excel, vba

Есть макрос для excel, привязываю его к фигуре, фигура находится в определенной ячейке. В данном случае в B6, как сделать так, чтобы мне не приходилось менять вручную адрес ячейки, а получать его в зависимости от места расположения фигуры? Например, фигура расположена в ячейке B9, соответственно получаю адрес ячейки из расположения фигуры и делаю уже инкремент.

```
Sub mac1()
    With Range("B6")
    If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    .Value = .Value + 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Зачем такие сложности с фигурами? Процедура, отслеживающая событие листа (выделение ячейки или DoubleClick). Кликнули - получили в ячейке +1

Comment: Что такое "фигура" в данном случае? Что, какое событие, вызывает выполнение макроса?

Comment: @vikttur, действительно, зачем мне фигура тогда. Выделение простое ячейки куда удобнее.

Comment: @Akina обычный клик по фигурке вызывал выполнение макроса, фигуры уже не актуальны получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие выделения ячейки (`ЛКМ`) не сосовсем удобно в данном случае.

Вариант: при `ПКМ` +1. Если ошиблись, отнять единичку -  `DoubleClick`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2:B100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Value = Target.Value + 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2:B100"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Value = Target.Value - 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Код разместить в модуле листа